# Soffit vent distance from facia

Tags: siding, roofing, soffit, new-home

I am installing soffit and vents from the outside on my house which is framed and dried-in (new construction). It is a large Victorian style, white farmhouse look. 2 story, already sheeted (roof and walls). 5.5" LP facia and drip edge is already installed. Intend to use 8" flat (no wood grain) LP siding as well. The ceiling cap is not installed (no drywall, no insulation yet). I'd like to do the soffit next. My space between walls and facia lip is 11".

I think I'd like to use my 5.5" and/or maybe 8" primed, LP siding product as soffit. And I suppose I'll use the long strips of vinyl vent that appear to be 3" wide. It would make sense to me, to put the vent right up against the facia lip that is hanging down and caulk it in between facia and soffit LP product. But, I see all recommendations to have at least 3" of soffit between the facia lip and the vent strips. Why?

Would make more sense to me, especially considering the plastic baffles I'm installing from ProVent that I would install that soffit vent as far away from the wall as possible. Why does everyone basically say not to do that? Why shouldn't I?

Comment: Just conjecture here, but wouldn't a bit of distance from facia to vent = distance of vent from moisture (rain, snow sleet etc.)?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I’d upvote this if it was an answer. I think keeping the vent opening far enough away from water running off the fascia so it can’t get blown up and into the vent opening is key.